# Send Json Array to MVC Controller brings Empty Models?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My controller as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getCartFromClient(List<JSItem> data)
{
   return view();
}
```

and My JS code to send Json as follow:

```
   var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
   $.ajax({

            url: "CheckOut/getCartFromClient/",

            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(list)
        });
```

Now the issue is , when the conttroller been called , data will contain the right number of items in the array, however the content of each JSItem is null , Id  is null the name is null .. !?

not sure what causing this issue! I get the right number of objects in the list but the content is null?

The ViewModel is as follow:

```
public class JSItem
{
    public string xid { get; set; }
    public string xamount { get; set; }
    public string xprice { get; set; }
    public string xname { get; set; }
    public string xlevel { get; set; }
    //public string ximg { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public JSItem JSItem { get; set; }
}
```

Json.stringify(list) will bring the following json file:

```
"[{"JSItem":{"xid":"2","xamount":"1","xprice":"50.00","xname":"BaBy Product 1","xlevel":"0"}},{"JSItem":{"xid":"3","xamount":"1","xprice":"0.00","xname":"BaBy Product 122","xlevel":"0"}}]"
```

Comment: What does `var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));` return and what is your `JSItem` model?

Comment: list return Array of items. which match exactly the  JSitem model in the backend .

Comment: public class JSItem
    {
        public string xid { get; set; }
        public string xamount { get; set; }
        public string xprice { get; set; }
        public string xname { get; set; }
        public string xlevel { get; set; }
            }

and this is how i inout JS to add items to cart LocalStorage :
     var b = { "JSItem": { "xid": id, "xamount": amount, "xprice": price, "xname": nameofitem, "xlevel": level } };

Comment: @H.Rashid , whenever binding fails check with the data you are sending in json , just cross check that with http://json2csharp.com/  it should match JSItem

Comment: In your question - not in comments

Comment: yeh i have used it to create VModel and yet ! the problem is the List<JSItem> Data , the list has the right number of object in it , yet the jsitem object they are all null !

Comment: Fixed the question with the rest of the cose @StephenMuecke Muecke

Comment: why dont you try passing the `list` without doing a JSON.stringify ?

Comment: same issue if i pass it as an object array i still get no data at the backend

Comment: In order to bind to `List<JSItem> data`, then `list` needs to be `var list = { data: [{ xid: '2', xamount: '1', xprice: '50.00', etc}, { etc }] };` (and why are you making your properties all `string` when they are clearly `int`, `decimal` etc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data seems to be one level above JSItem.

Change your controller action to RootObject and see.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getCartFromClient(List<RootObject> data)
{
   return view();
}
```

if you don't want to do this, then send the JSOn as Stephen Muecke suggested in the comments, for it to be deserialized as `List<JSItem>`

And as to why you see the right count for `List<JSItem>`, but all null values, the reason is this:

When MVC tries to deserialize this value into the `List<JSItem>`

```
"[
 {
  "JSItem":{"xid":"2","xamount":"1","xprice":"50.00","xname":"BaBy Product 1","xlevel":"0"}
 },
 {
  "JSItem":{"xid":"3","xamount":"1","xprice":"0.00","xname":"BaBy Product 122","xlevel":"0"}
 }
 ]"
```

MVC is able to recognize that the input is an array of elements with count 2.
So it initialized the `List<JSItem>` with 2 elements. And it starts newing up `JSItem` for every item, as part of model binding.

However when it tries to set the properties of this newed up `JSItem`, it doesn't find any matching fields in the JSON. this is because your JSON is one level above the `JSItem`. Hence all fields are null.